# Spring client for server send events

Tags: spring

I am using the ResponseBodyEmitter in Spring 4.2 RC1 for sending JSON object as part of the server send events. I am able to see the response in web browser. Is there any spring client for the same ?

I tried using AsyncRestTemplate, but I am getting all the response together. Ie if I am sending 3 objects one after another using ResponseBodyEmitter , using AsyncRestTemplate, I get all of them together. I would like to receive in client as and when the server sends it.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a go to Reactor HTTP client if you're into async and reactive programming: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-net/src/test/groovy/reactor/io/net/http/HttpSpec.groovy#L74.

Comment: I am not able to access https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-net/src/test/groovy/reactor/io/net/http/HttpSpec.groovy#L74.  Does spring has any SSE support client ?